# GridDB: The connection already been lost(NewSQL/NoSQL)

Tags: nosql, griddb, connection-close

I am attempting to access/create containers, databases, and tables in `GridDB` using `SQL` and GridDB Web CLI. However, when I execute the command to show/create the container and write SQL queries, I encounter an error:

> This connection has already been closed (NoSQL)/(NewSQL)

as clearly shown in the screenshot.
[image: error screenshot]

I have checked the server status, and it is currently running. To confirm, I have also restarted the GridDB server. The CPU, memory, etc., have been checked, and all the necessary requirements have been met. However, despite these confirmations, I am still encountering the error. It is possible that I may have missed some configurations or properties that could be causing this issue. I kindly request guidance on how to fix this problem so that I can continue my work.

Answer (score 1):

These errors occur as a result of running the SQL or TQL commands outside the **gsadm** user. To fix this error, you will need to switch to the gsadm before running the GridDB shell, SQL and TQL commands using;

ON Linux, Ubuntu, WSL environment.

```
sudo su gsadm
gs_sh
```

While on docker, check [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041337/3410041) to get more guide to resolve the error.