# Grid DB Docker "This connection has already been closed (NOSQL)"

Tags: griddb

I ran into a logical error "This connection has already been closed (NOSQL)." while running Grid DB Shell commands on Docker.

[image: grid db connection closed error]

Following the [documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/docker/#nodejs-application-container) on installation of Grid DB on Docker, I ran the command

```
docker exec -it griddb-server gs_sh
```

to start my Grid DB server on Docker and attempt to run some GridDB shell command

`showcontainer`

However, I didn't get the list of container on the Grid DB database. I expect a response that show a table list of containers (available or not available) on the Grid DB database but got the response "This connection has already been closed (NOSQL)."

I tried other Grid Shell command and some SQL commands but got same response.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve this issue.

I realize that the error occurs due to starting the Grid Shell on root user instead of gsadm on your environment (most likely docker when running `docker exec -it griddb-server gs_sh`)

If you are using the docker environment, I will recommend you follow the steps below;

1. `docker exec -it griddb-server gs_stat -u admin/admin` To start the griddb-server
2. `docker exec -it griddb-server /bin/bash` To enter the griddb server environment
3. `su gsadm` To change to the user gsadm where we can access the griddb-server
4. `gs_sh` To enter the griddb shell and run successfully Grid DB command

While on other environment;
You need to ensure you run the following commands before running SQL or TQL commands;

```
sudo su gsadm
gs_sh
```